Longest sentence using 4 letters (and punctuation marks)
Inspired by Long word using only 4 letters -
Using only four distinct letters and four punctuation marks (e.g. commas, semicolons, and apostrophes, not including the ending period), can you form a grammatically sound sentence with at least 13 valid English words, all of which are unique?

Note: You may use proper nouns to extend your sentence, but they will not count as valid English words (i.e. words that can be found in Merriam-Webster or Oxford dictionaries).


What counts as a valid sentence? What counts as a word?

@Deusovi and other downvoters, I've edited the question to be more well-defined so that answers can be validated more easily as "correct" (which I would guess was the main gripe.)

I’ve added a restriction on the amount of punctuation you can include.

Basic: One with 13 unique valid English words, using 4 punctuation marks:

 See Al sass lass Ella’s sea seal lease sales; ales, leas, leases all sell less. (Letters: AELS)

Improved: One with 17 unique valid English words, using just 1 punctuation mark (letters courtesy of @bobble):

 A tea set asset at east sea teases estates; See attests estate ass seats tease test seat assets. (Letters: AEST)


I consider semicolons cheating :p

haha you do have a point there :p

(but yeah, this has been somewhat addressed by the punctuation mark limit!)
